# Properties across classes in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective C, so please forgive the simplicity of my question.

I have a class, lets call it `Class A` and it looks like this

```
@interface A()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segment;
@end

@implementation A
  ...
```

Now what I want to do, is "get" the segment in `class B`. I have tried doing this by  doing this

```
@interface B()
@property (nonatomic) B *cardy;
@end

@implementation B
 ...
```

I then want to do `cardy.segment`, but I cannot seem to access it. I tried using `@synthesize` in A but need to ensure exactly how to implement the "get" properly.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens, when you try to access it? Also, you usually don't need @synthesize with current versions of the compiler. You get getters and setters for free if you have a property.

Comment: If i try and do if (*cardy.segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) i get the error "use of the undeclared identified cardy).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?
If you want to access a property use this.cardy, but I don't see what you are trying to achieve. Why is cardy of the B not A, if a is the class where segment has been defined?

Comment: A is the controller for my storyboard and B contains my model. I want to check whether a user has selected a particular state for the UI slider and do something different in B depending on the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the property in the .h file, not the .m file. Also, make sure A.h is imported in B.m

Comment: Still struggling with this. Declared the property in A.h and imported  it in B.m but still cannot do cardy.segment..

Comment: Declare the property  like: @property (nonatomic, strong) B *cardy; and access it like: self.cardy.segment or _cardy.segment